# JavaScript form validation, does not complete full script before continuing

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm having trouble with a JavaScript form validation script.

Essentially if an answer hasn't been given, it should mark the question as red and not  submit the form. (It adds the red by giving the class `error` to the question)

My form is set up to POST through to another script but I want to handle the validation before POSTing so have used `onsubmit` to run the validation:

```
<form name="questionnaire" action="my-questionnaire.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

So it runs this script. If it gets a `false` result then it makes the question red and then fill it in again.

What I can't understand is that it still always POST's the form after the first `if` statement. I have noted with a comment where it gets to before it POST's. It never gets further than this, even though nothing has been returned `true` yet.

```js
function validateForm() {
  var features = document.forms["questionnaire"]["features"].value;
  if (features == null || features == "") {
    var qFeature = document.getElementById("qOne");
    qFeature.className = qFeature.className + " error";
    return false;
  } else {
    qFeature.className = qFeature.className + " noerror";
  }

  // POST's form anyway here
  var freeDel = document.forms["questionnaire"]["importance-free-delivery"].value;
  if (freeDel == null || freeDel == "") {
    var qFreeDel = document.getElementById("qTwoOne");
    qFreeDel.className = qFreeDel.className + " error";
    return false;
  } else {
    qFreeDel.className = qFreeDel.className + " noerror";
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<form name="questionnaire" action="my-questionnaire.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <h2 id="qOne" class="question">1) What product features do you specifically look for when renting a vehicle/s for your business:</h2>
  <input type="radio" name="features" value="free-delivery-and-collection">Free Delivery and Collection
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="features" value="fixed-price">A fixed price
  <br />

  <h2 id="qTwo" class="question">2) Rank the below in terms of importance. (1 = not very important, 5 = very important)</h2>
  1
  <input type="radio" name="importance-free-delivery" value="1">
  <br />2
  <input type="radio" name="importance-free-delivery" value="2">
  <br />3
  <input type="radio" name="importance-free-delivery" value="3">
  <br />4
  <input type="radio" name="importance-free-delivery" value="4">
  <br />5
  <input type="radio" name="importance-free-delivery" value="5">
  <br />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit Questionnaire" class="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: If you add the rest of the form and then turn it into a code snippet (ctrl + k) you would increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: @Mandera have added form.

Comment: `document.forms["questionnaire"]["importance-free-delivery"]` returns a NodeList, it has not `value` property.

Comment: @Teemu can you suggest an alternative to this then that works as per the first question? I am confused as the first one works fine.

Comment: One issue is that qFeature is undefined in the else section: `else { qFeature.className = qFeature.className + " noerror"; }`

Comment: @Mandera however it works fine? Does not give any errors?

Comment: Which first question? In this type of event handling, if an error occurs in the handler, nothing is returned, and submitting is happening by default, and even erranous code seems to work as expected.

Comment: @Francesca Do you really not see any errors? I'm seeing an error in my console when I run your snippet: "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined`" (in the `else` block, where you haven't defined `qFeature`)

Comment: This way of stopping a form submit doesn't work anymore. See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp and http://jsfiddle.net/p8owgvqh/

Comment: @Mandera It works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/p8owgvqh/1/. JSFiddle wraps your functions in a closure, so you need to explicitly assign your globals as members of `window` (e.g., `window.validateForm = function() { ... }`). If you look at your console, you'll see it complains that `validateForm is not defined`, because it's not global in your fiddle.

Comment: @apsillers Oh I didn't know that, your updated version called the alert but it still submitted though.

Comment: @Mandera Sorry, I forgot to make it `return validateForm()` in my updated version. This works: http://jsfiddle.net/p8owgvqh/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onsubmit` doesn't *permit* the form to submit by returning `true`, but rather it can *prevent* the form from submitting by returning `false`. If your `onsubmit` function fails to `return false` for any reason, the form submission will proceed.

In your case, you have code that produces an error when the `features` field passes validation. When this error is thrown, the function terminates *immediately*, and the validation code for the `importance-free-delivery` field never has a chance to `return false` (so submission is not prevented).

The error is that you use `qFeature` in your `else` block without defining it. `qFeature` is definied in your `if` block, but obviously if your `else` block is running, your `if` block *didn't run*. Instead, move the definition of `qFeature` outside of the `if`:

```
var qFeature = document.getElementById("qOne");

if (features == null || features == "") {
  qFeature.className = qFeature.className + " error";
  return false;
} else {
  qFeature.className = qFeature.className + " noerror";
}
```

You have an identical error with `qFreeDel` in the next part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contained a lot of errors.

- `document.forms["questionnaire"]["features"]` returns an array of nodes, so you can't get it's `value` attribute, you need to loop through every node and check if it's `checked` attribute is true.
- `document.getElementById("qTwoOne")` should be `qTwo`.
- Some variables were only defined in the `if` block, so in the `else` block they were undefined.

I rewrote your code:

```js
function checkIfRadioOptionIsSelected(nodeArray) {
    for (var i in nodeArray) {
        if (nodeArray[i].checked) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

window.validateForm = function () {

    var featuresSelected = checkIfRadioOptionIsSelected(document.forms["questionnaire"]["features"]);
    var importanceSelected = checkIfRadioOptionIsSelected(document.forms["questionnaire"]["importance-free-delivery"]);

    var qOne = document.getElementById("qOne");
    if(!qOne.originalClass) qOne.originalClass = qOne.className;
    qOne.className = qOne.originalClass + (featuresSelected ? " noerror" : " error");

    var qTwo = document.getElementById("qTwo");
    if(!qTwo.originalClass) qTwo.originalClass = qTwo.className;
    qTwo.className = qTwo.originalClass + (importanceSelected ? " noerror" : " error");

    if(!featuresSelected  || !importanceSelected) return false;
    return true;
}
```

```css
.error {
    color: red;
}

.noerror {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<form name="questionnaire" action="my-questionnaire.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
     <h2 id="qOne" class="question">1) What product features do you specifically look for when renting a vehicle/s for your business:</h2>

    <input type="radio" name="features" value="free-delivery-and-collection">Free Delivery and Collection
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="features" value="fixed-price">A fixed price
    <br />
     <h2 id="qTwo" class="question">2) Rank the below in terms of importance. (1 = not very important, 5 = very important)</h2>
1
    <input type="radio" name="importance-free-delivery" value="1">
    <br />2
    <input type="radio" name="importance-free-delivery" value="2">
    <br />3
    <input type="radio" name="importance-free-delivery" value="3">
    <br />4
    <input type="radio" name="importance-free-delivery" value="4">
    <br />5
    <input type="radio" name="importance-free-delivery" value="5">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Questionnaire" class="submit" />
</form>
```

P.S: The form submission is blocked in snippets.